# database modeling with multiple many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity, data-modeling

I have 3 entities

- workers
- students
- addresses

Each worker can have multiple addresses. Each student can have multiple addresses. Each address can be the address of x students and y workers.

My question is, how does the best data modeling look like. Implement the many-to-many relation in only one associative table for everything like so:

```
ID | Address_ID | Worker_ID | Student_ID
```

where **ID** is PK and **Worker_ID** or **Student_ID** can be null

or 2 tables like so:

```
Address_ID | Worker_ID
```

PK is **Address_ID** and **Worker_ID**

and

```
Address_ID | Student_ID
```

PK is **Address_I**D and **Student_ID**

Which option is the best and maybe why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that address is not the only field that applies to both students and workers.  I would be tempted to create a 'persons' entity that stored global information, and then add a relationship to both students and workers back to the persons table.  This has the additional benefit of allowing students to also be workers.

Comment: Echoing other comments, you definitely want to have a "persons" or "members" table, and have a separate table (or column) that defines the capacity in which the person/member relates to the organisation. The next question is then, can the same person relate in more than one capacity - for example, can a worker also be a student? And do their addresses relate to the member themselves, or to their capacities? For example, a student member may want both home and term-time addresses recorded, whereas that distinction is possibly meaningless in relation to the same member in a worker capacity.

Comment: What Dan Farrell said.  The relationships between students or workers and persons are IS-A relationships.  Students and workers can both be identified by person-id.  Look up Class Table Inheritance for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First of all**: it is not good modeling techniques:

> Each address can be the address of x students and y workers

There is no need to specify an `Address` to two or more `Students` or `Workers`. If they have same `Address` you can repeat the `Address`. **Note that**: How many Students and Workers have the same Address?

**In this case**: **Redundancy is better that Complexity**.

**Secondly**: Your first approach is wrong (`ID | Address_ID | Worker_ID | Student_ID`) and make a **Nullification** trap in database. Your second approach is better.

**Thirdly**: I offer third approach. 
You have `Worker` and `Student` tables. So absolutely these tables have **common attributes**. So You can make another table named it: `Person`. Then put all common attributes in it. Then you can relate `Person` with `Address` (many-to-many or one-to-many)

In this case there is inheritance between `Worker` and `Person` (and `Student` and `Person`). To **Mapping the inheritance to relational model**, you can use one-to-one relationship between `Worker` and `Person` (and `Student` and `Person`). In these one-to-one relationships, it's better to transfer `Person_ID` to `Worker` (and `Person_ID` to `Student`).

Comment: Good answer.  A better reason to break out address would be if persons might have multiple addresses .

Answer (score 1):

I have some questions.

Why you decided to make an Address table?

How many searches in you system are based on Address fields?

You can use Address as a String field. In database design we change a multi-field field to table in some conditions. The important condition is searching the fields are so much.

For example in Post System or Telephone or Address Finding System, not in regular systems.